# Escaping hash and quote to regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex, escaping

I am trying to define a regular to use with a regular expression validator that limits the content of a textbox to only alphanumeric characters, slash (/), hash (#), left and right parentheses (()), period (.), apostrophe ('), quote ("), hyphen (-) and spaces.

I am having troubles with the hash and quote, the other restrictions are working, but when I insert one of these chars the evaluation fails and I get the error message. I have tried to escape these characters without and also using verbatim which was my last attempt.

```
@"[ a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ/().\'-""#]"
```

Any thoughts on these? Thank you

Comment: `I get the error message` Mind telling us what that is? **Show us your code**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex language is smart enough to understand that periods and parentheses within a character class actually refer to the characters and not to the patterns they usually do when they appear outside of character classes.

Within your character class, you need to escape the slash (`\`) and the hyphen(`-`), but that's it:

```
@"[ a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ/().\\'\-""#]"
```

If you move your hyphen to the end of the character class, you won't even need to escape that:

```
@"[ a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ/().\\'""#-]"
```

And of course this still only matches one a single character. If you want to ensure that the entire string consists only of these characters, you'll need to use start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors and a quantifier (`*` or `+`) after your character class.

I believe your final pattern should look like this:

```
@"^[ a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ/().\\'""#-]*$"
```